# Getting Tablename from trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am making a trigger on database which will stop the deletion of table from my data base but I only wants to apply it on particulate table not for all, for this I want to get the table name from deleted table of trigger which inserted while the drop command got execute. I have made a trigger here kindly give a look below. Please help me for doing this task I really needed this completed.

```
Create TRIGGER [NO_DROP_Veripda] ON database 
for delete
declare @table SYSNAME
select @table= ???? --Here I need help How Can I get table name and insert in this veriable
print @table
IF  exists (select sys.sysobjects.name from sys.sysobjects where @table in ('test1','caseflds_bk'))
    PRINT 'Dropping tables are not allowed!!!'
else 
BEGIN
 DISABLE TRIGGER [NO_DROP_Veripda] ON DATABASE
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ''
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    begin
        enable TRIGGER [NO_DROP_Veripda] ON DATABASE
    end
 END
```

Comment: I assume you must be talking about [sql-server] based on the syntax and fact that MySQL only allows triggers to be created on specific tables.

Comment: If you want to prevent something from happening, the easiest way to do that is to not give people permission to perform that activity at all - why are you giving people permissions to drop tables that you don't want them to?

Comment: Multi pal users works on the database or by mistake many time it happen that the table got deleted so I have assume of doing this as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a DML trigger. You need to use a [DDL trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.105).aspx) along with the [Event Data function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909.aspx).

See this [Link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1141863-338-1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answering me..I did as mention in the [Event Data][1] 
  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909.aspx                                              and modify my trigger